# problemas con routerLink

Tags: angular, vscode, routerlink

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo Angular y al momento de poner mi ruta con RouterLink para direccionar a Login no está funcionando, resulta que tengo importado y exportado el routerModule y el orden de mis carpetas al parecer no es el problema, probé de 2 formas pensando que podía ser el orden de mis archivos y tampoco se solucionó, adjuntaré imagenes del auth-routing.module.ts [image: auth-ruting.module.ts]
[image: auth-routing.module.ts parte 2]
[image: orden de mis archivos]
[image: app-routing.module.ts]
[image: app-routing.module ts parte 2]

Comment: Por favor, agrega cómo esta tu app-routing-module para llegar al error, seguramente al cargar el modulo auth hay un error.

Comment: hola buenas noches Juan acabo de añadir el app-routing.module.ts en las imagenes

Comment: El codigo se debe subir en formato texto y no en imagenes, lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes varios Modulos creado , dedusco que has ido practicando lo que has visto en diferentes videos.

**Fijate si en**

auth.module.ts

**estes importantando**

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';
import {AuthRoutingModule } from '../auth-routing.module';

@NgModule({             
imports: [AppRoutingModule,AuthRoutingModule]
})
```